# how to get text color from adjacent text

Tags: java, android, textcolor

I am working on an android app where I can apply different colors to text of edittext using spannable strings and getting colors through the ActivityResult and it is working great but when I start typing more text it get the default color which is black. Please note that I am using only one edittext. Now I want to add a function where one can type in the color after selecting the color. Also, I want the other function where when one click near the other color text it gets that text color automatically and when one starts typing it types in that color. Mean I want to get color from adjacent text color. 
 I tried the following but it colors my whole text. I don't want my whole text to get the same color.

```
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
```

Here is my spannable string color coding which is working fine.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RequestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        color = data.getStringExtra("color");
        texto.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
    Spannable str = texto.getText();
    int selStart = texto.getSelectionStart();
    int selEnd = texto.getSelectionEnd();
    ForegroundColorSpan[] styleSpans = texto.getText().getSpans(selStart, selEnd, ForegroundColorSpan.class);

    if (styleSpans.length > 0) {
        int lastSpanEnd = 0;
        for (ForegroundColorSpan styleSpan : styleSpans) {
            int oldStyle = styleSpan.getForegroundColor();
            int spanStart = str.getSpanStart(styleSpan);
            int spanEnd = str.getSpanEnd(styleSpan);
            str.removeSpan(styleSpan);
            if (spanStart < selStart) {
                str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(oldStyle), spanStart, selStart, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }

            if (spanEnd > selEnd) {
                str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(oldStyle), selEnd, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }

        if (selEnd != lastSpanEnd) {
            str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(color)), selStart, selEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }

    else {
        str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(color)), selStart, selEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```